# What happened to my file selection dialogs? (Windows 7 64-bit)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

My file select dialogs have gone a little crazy in a lot of applications (Firefox, Chrome, Winamp, etc. - maybe it's all MFC apps but I'm not sure). The nav bar and sidebar are blank or missing. Does anyone have any idea what happened or how to get it back to normal?

[image: Thanks for embedding the screenshot, studiohack =D]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be that one or more system files is corrupted. Try the Windows Resource Checker (aka System File Checker).

Open an elevated command prompt.

1. Go to All Programs | Accessories.
2. Right-click on Command Prompt.
3. Choose Run As Administrator.

From the command prompt, type `sfc /scannow`.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Turns out Windows didn't like being cloned onto a new drive.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try a system restore

2) Try this Microsoft Fix It Utility:

Diagnose and repair Windows File and Folder Problems automatically

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_file_and_folder_diag/en-us

3) Try the solution recommended by Patrick S. (sfc...)

Hope this help. Let us know.  :)